# javascript onload function shows changes for a second then reverts back

Tags: javascript, html, razor, blazor, razor-pages

I have a javascript file like below which changes the innerHtml value of a header.

```
window.addEventListener("onload", function (e) {
    console.log("Hit Javascript file");
    if (this.document.getElementById('cardHeader')) {
        document.getElementById('cardHeader').innerHTML = "Card Header Text";
    }
});
```

The changes are noticeable for half a second and then it reverts back to its original value. I tried using defer incase the page wasn't fully loaded. I also tried positioning the script tag inside the header, body and outside the body.

Inside my layout html this is where i've added the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>


<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="https://mysitehere.azurewebsites.net/login-script.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you read [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#interaction-with-the-document-object-model-dom) regarding DOM manipulation in a Blazor app?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `onload` is an incorrect parameter to be used with `window.addEventListener`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event
Try

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    console.log("Hit Javascript file");
    if (document.getElementById('cardHeader')) {
        document.getElementById('cardHeader').innerHTML = "Card Header Text";
    }
});
```

instead.
Alternatively,

```
window.onload = (event) => {
    console.log("Hit Javascript file");
    if (document.getElementById('cardHeader')) {
        document.getElementById('cardHeader').innerHTML = "Card Header Text";
    }
};
```

Comment: Also good to know is the `DOMContentLoaded` event - usually more appropriate than `load` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score -1):

In the first parameter of `addEventListener()`, `"onload"` should just be `"load"`:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    console.log("Hit Javascript file");
    if (document.getElementById('cardHeader')) {
        document.getElementById('cardHeader').innerHTML = "Card Header Text";
    }
}, false);
```